# Using vscode to develop a flutter app, but after stopping the debugging and opening the app on the phone, it loads the previous version

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am using Vscode for developing flutter apps. After running the app in debug mode on my phone and stopped the debugging, then opened the app on the phone, it loads the previous version instead of the current one.

Comment: yeah, it happens for me too. Try running flutter run before stopping the debug. This would help you to get the current version of your app.

Comment: wipedata and run again.

Comment: @SanjeevAV is it after stopping the current debug session, or while still running?

Comment: @Abdimussa as given below run the app again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hot reloads/restarts don't exist after ending the debugging session.

If you want to keep the updated app on the phone after debugging,

1. Stop the debug session
2. Run the app again

Answer (score 1):

Open AVD Manager. Select the emulator that you are running the app.

`WipeData` and run again in same emulator.